# Option to change subtitle font size is missing in VLC

Tags: video, fonts, vlc-media-player, subtitles

The option to customize the font size in pixels is usually located in the advanced settings at `(Show settings: All) Video > Subtitles/OSD > Text renderer`, but the option is missing.

The option to change the relative size of the subtitles in `(Show settings: Simple) Subtitles/OSD > Subtitle effects > Font size` is also missing.

Is anyone else facing the issue? Any suggestions are appreciated. [Screenshot of Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLclY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the latest VLV 3.0.8:

- I have under Text renderer both "Font size in pixels" and "Relative font size".
- I also have under Subtitle effects the entry for Font size.

I suggest to uninstall and install the latest version.

If this doesn't help: Are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: This worked. Sorry for replying late.